# Make a post request with Alamofire 5 with XML body

Tags: xml, post, soap, alamofire, swift5

I'm trying to make a request to a SOAP service with Alamofire version 5 and swift 5. The request look like this:

```
AF.request("URL-endpoint"), method: .post)
 .authenticate(username: "user", password: "password")
 .responseData{ (data) in 
   print(data) 
}
```

How can I insert a body xml in this request? The response of the post request is an XML that later I will treat it with a parser.